Film to Block UV light but allow Heat to pass
Can a window film be applied to block UV light and still allow the heat to pass through? The situation is passively designed house in Australia relying on the sun to pass through the north-facing windows for heating during winter but protect from direct sunlight by the eaves in Summer.

I don't know if a film is available for this purpose. But glass used when framing art is often a formula that blocks, or at least reduces, ultraviolet light to help keep the art from fading. I would presume something similar can be done with window glass, though to get all the desired characteristics it might need to be layered with other kinds of glass.

That should definitely be possible, especially since UV radiation and heat (IR/Infra-red radiation) are at different ends of the visible light spectrum.

You can definitely buy windows that do this, probably more effectively than any film.  They can also apply coatings to allow light in while holding heat in at the same time.

@mdfst13 you don't seem to understand. It is too expansive to replace the windows and I still need heat to transfer through the windows.

You don't want heat to transfer from inside the house to outside.  You do need light (including infrared but not ultraviolet) to transfer from outside to inside.  Beyond that, of course I don't understand requirements that you didn't put into the question.  As is, if there's a film that's more expensive but less effective than replacing the windows, you're asking people to recommend it even if that's not what you need.

??? Seems you just make this crap up. Stick to the question - "allow the heat to pass through"  ie both ways. When the sun goes down in winter the curtains are drawn to block heat loss. I'm not asking about replacing windows and if the film is too expensive to be cost effective then it won't be an option.

They are available.
The first one in my Google search.  I am not associated with it.  They market this one as UV only.  But it has minor effects on other wavelengths.

UV Protection Window Film AUVF
Ultraviolet (UV) light is responsible for 40% of the causes of fading. Our UV protection window film reduces UV rays by 99% whilst still being completely clear and therefore unnoticeable once applied on the glass. At Purlfrost, UV window film can be purchased by the metre in a length and width of your choice, or for ease of installation cut to size.


